# Set Dynemic index value in multidimesnsion array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My html page like this (View)

```
  foreach ($va as $key=>$value) {

?>
<td>
    <?= $value->id; ?> <input type="hidden" name="mark[1][sid]" value="<?= $value->id; ?>" >
    <input type="text" name=" mark[1][maths]"  >
    <input type="text"  name="mark[1][ss]">
    <input type="text"  name="mark[1][science]">
    <input type="text"  name="mark[1][english]"> 
    </td>
```

MY Controller like this

```
 $data=$this->input->post();
            echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

Display Scrrenshot Like this
[Html Page (View)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6am3.png)

And my output is like [Output Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2xOj.png)

This output display only last row data but I fill all data into textbox so what is problem to show all details or full array

And second how to set dynamic index in Multidimensional Array mark[$dynamic_index][sid]

i use `<input type="text" name=" mark[$key][maths]"  >`

But Not Working

I can display all array data and generate dynamic index(key) in array

Thanks Advance

Comment: You said you are using like `<input type="text" name=" mark[$key][maths]"  >` but in your questions I can see hard coded `1` instead of dynamic `$key`

Answer (score 0):

Hello Just use below code

```
<?php
$count=0;
foreach ($va as $key=>$value) {

?>
<td>
    <?= $value->id; ?> <input type="hidden" name="mark[1][sid]" value="<?= $value->id; ?>" >
    <input type="text" name=" mark[<?php echo $count; ?>][maths]"  >
    <input type="text"  name="mark[<?php echo $count; ?>][ss]">
    <input type="text"  name="mark[<?php echo $count; ?>][science]">
    <input type="text"  name="mark[<?php echo $count; ?>][english]"> 
</td>
<?php 
$count++;
}
?>
```